# Issue in installing PyOpenCL

Tags: python, c++, ubuntu, opencl, pyopencl

I'm trying to install [PyOpenCL](https://mathema.tician.de/software/pyopencl/) on Ubuntu 16.04, but getting the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenCL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'c++' failed with exit status 1
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: By installing `c++`? e.g. `sudo apt-get install libstdc++-6-dev`.

Comment: Willem that is not correct. OP needs to install `libOpenCL.so` which can be done on ubuntu by installing package `ocl-icd-opencl-dev`. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install: ocl-icd-opencl-dev

`apt-get install ocl-icd-opencl-dev`

You can check what was actually installed with that package running:

```
$ dpkg -L ocl-icd-opencl-dev
```

which should return something along these lines:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/ocl-icd-opencl-dev
/usr/share/doc/ocl-icd-opencl-dev/copyright
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/OpenCL.pc
/usr/share/doc/ocl-icd-opencl-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so  # <--- this is the important bit
```

---

#### Bonus

If you get a complaint about missing headers, e.g CL/cl.h, then you should install:

`apt-get install opencl-headers`.

Don't forget to install specific OpenCL drivers for your platform. You could be running against an Intel CPU/GPU, an AMD or NVidia graphics card or even an FPGA.

A good way of checking everything is well setup, is to run `clinfo` which will show useful information about available platforms (`apt-get install clinfo`).

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this page](https://wiki.tiker.net/PyOpenCL/Installation/Linux/Ubuntu), it seems that I had to only run this command on my bash for the error to be removed:

```
apt-get install python-pyopencl
```